# Adding elements to List<> doesn't work

Tags: c#, collections, null

I have a List<> declared, which is accessable in the whole class

```
List<article> data;
```

Now I'm using a method to fill the List<>:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');

    article newArticle = new article();
    newArticle.articleNumber = Line[0];
    newArticle.description = Line[1];
    newArticle.articleId = Line[2];
    try
    {
        data.Add(newArticle);
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }
}
```

Each time, the loop repeats, the newArticle-Object contains all his elements, so it is definetely not null.
But it doesn't add to the data-List<>.
What am I missing?

Comment: how about the `data`? are you initializing the list before calling `Add` method? and why are you swallowing NullReferenceException ?

Comment: How often does it get in the `catch` block?

Comment: The `newArticle` may not be null, but the `data` list of articles definitely is

Comment: What they are saying is do: List<article> data = new List<article>();

Comment: ahh.. damn.. that's definetely not my day

Comment: Why are people down voting this question with such ferocity? @Marcel has described the problem, he's posted his code and is just unclear about the response he is seeing in his debugger. A search on his part would possibly have returned a solution, but from the question it appears he wasn't sure of what was causing the issue.

Comment: @Bara'thorn: Him catching a `NullReferenceException` clearly does show he knows what happened. A simple search on it does reveal the actual reason. Instead of ignoring it by putting an empty `catch` he could have fixed the issue. Also, the downvote button gives more reasons to downvote.

Comment: can you please tell use on which line the exception happens? @Marcel

Comment: Can you post some more code? we would like to focus more on "data" variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add items to the list, you must first initialise it.

Replace:

```
List<article> data;
```

with:

```
List<article> data = new List<article>();
```

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot that :P thank you :)